# synchronizing two mysql databases in vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net

I am trying to sync two mysql databases.
I have managed to sync a table with this method:

```vb
Dim oldbcon As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=psugsonline;userid=root;password=;")
Dim dbconn As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=psugs;userid=root;password=;")

Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from tbusers where sync='false'", dbconn)
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.Clear()
da.Fill(ds)
If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

        Dim instbuser As New MySqlCommand("insert into tbusers values('" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)(0).ToString & "','" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)(1).ToString & "','" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)(2).ToString & "','" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)(3).ToString & "','true')", oldbcon)
        oldbcon.Open()
        instbuser.ExecuteNonQuery()
        oldbcon.Close()
    Next
End If
```

But this method only applies to one of my tables and if the table structure changes this method would not work.

I've to sync 16 tables.How can i achieve this?

Comment: use procedure to do the insert so when you edit table structure you don't need to edit the code only edit the  procedure

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim listOfConnectionStrings = New List(Of String)
listOfConnectionStrings.Add(connectionString1)
listOfConnectionStrings.Add(connectionString2)
```

etc.

Then connect to your source database as you have already done and build up your query string (i.e. INSERT INTO TABLE (X, Y, Z) VALUES (A, B C)

Finally

```
For Each str In listOfConnectionStrings
'connect to the database and run the insert statement against it
Next
```

"if the table structure changes this method would not work" - how often will the table structure change? If it does then find out about it in advance and modify your code to deal with the change.

Comment: i have 16 tables to sync and each table has different number of fields. thats why my code above cannot cope up with other tables in my database. thanks for the help man!